# Closed formula or approximations for $\sum_{i=2}^{n} \lfloor \log_{i}(n) \rfloor$

Tags: summation, logarithms, approximation, closed-form

I was working on this problem:

> How many integer pairs $ 2\le x, y \le 2019$ exist such that $\log_x(y)$ is an integer?

I found this to be $$\sum_{i=2}^{2019} \lfloor \log_i(2019) \rfloor = 2086$$

This led me to the question of a general formula or an asymptotic approximation for $f(n) = \sum_{i=2}^{n} \lfloor \log_{i}(n) \rfloor$. A "more continuous" version of this would be $g(n) = \sum_{i=2}^{n} \log_{i}(n)$, while an even more continuous version would be $h(n)=\int_2^n \log_x(n)dx$.

I wasn't able to find an approximation or bounds for $f(n)$, but did manage to get an asymptotic recurrence relation of $$f(n^2) \approx n^2-n+2f(n)$$

For $g(n)$, I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757900/is-this-summation-solvable-s-n-sum-i-2n-log-in) which shows that $$g(n) = \text{li}(n) \ln(n) + C \ln(n) + O(1)$$ where $C=\frac{1}{\log2}+\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}}{x\log^{2}x}dx$

and I found that $$h(n) = \int_2^{n} \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(x)} dx = \ln(n)(\text{li}(n)-\text{li}(2))$$

Can I get a closed formula for $f(n)$? If not, how can I find bounds?

Comment: It is also equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left\lfloor2019^{1/n}\right\rfloor -1\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\log_i n\ge k \iff n\ge i^k \iff i\le\sqrt[k]{n}$.

We can use this to rewrite the sum in terms of the number of integers $i,k$ for which this is satisfied.
$$
\sum_{i=2}^n \lfloor\log_i n\rfloor
= \sum_{i=2}^n \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_i n\rfloor} 1
= \sum_{\substack{2\le i\le n \\ 1\le k\\ i^k\le n}} 1
= \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} \sum_{i=2}^{\lfloor\sqrt[k]{n}\rfloor} 1
= \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} \lfloor\sqrt[k]{n}\rfloor - 1
$$
Note that the upper bound of $k\le\log_2 n$ may be placed since higher values do not contribute.

I doubt if there is a simple closed form for this.

In terms of approximations, you may note that the size of the terms $\lfloor\sqrt[k]{n}\rfloor-1$ drops fast as $k$ increases, so just the first few terms of the sum should provide a good approximation except for very small $n$.